# Add STL lib to mac os x bin

Tags: c++, macos, stl

I download the STL library to do some test with it, but the folder does not have a "configure, make, make install " files.
How can i add it to bin? 
So i can use always

```
    #include <vector.h>
```

instead of

```
    #include "vector.h"
```

and add the STL folder in all my project.
[image]

Comment: If you have installed the Apple Developer tools (Xcode) then you should already have STL.

Comment: do you really want the stl as opposed to the C++ standard library?

Comment: i had Xcode but when using  #include <vector.h> or  #include <iostream.h> Xcode says that it can find the files

Comment: @juanchopanza trying to code some example who uses STL

Comment: Most of STL is in the C++ standard library, so it is quite likely that you can implement your code using standard C++.

Comment: Just to emphasize rubenvb; do not put `.h` on the end of the header names. That's probably why Xcode couldn't find the headers. If the examples you're looking at use `.h` then they're too old.

Comment: Are you actually doing this in a C++ or Objective-C++ file (`.cpp` / `.mm`)?

Answer (score 2):

If you install a C++ compiler it will ship with a C++ Standard Library implementation with includes the STL (STLPort?) you're talking about.

XCode and also macports gcc include this. You should not be setting this up like you are now.

Also note that the Standard library headers do not have a `.h` suffix. So you need

```
#include <vector>
```

Comment: yep i know it should but whetn include the files Xcode says that it could not be found

Comment: @RubenVeiga, make sure your file has the C++/ObjC++ extension (.cpp or .mm, respectively)

Comment: uhm ok maybe thats the problem I'm coding in C